# can phpMyAdmin MIME point to local file and thumbnail? file:\\

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mime

I am trying to get phpMyAdmin to show the image/link for a field that has a local path.
For example, the path of my picture is **Z:/Koala.jpg**.

I've setup **MIME type: plain/txt** and the **Browser Transformation: txt/plain imagelink**.
It works for online images where the picture has http:// but not for files stored on my local hard drive.

It actually shows the **Z:/Koala.jpg** as a link and underlined, but it won't open anything when I click. phpMyAdmin appends file:\\ but I've tried both ways and no luck. Multiple browsers too.

PS Z:/ is a mapped network drive of my Network attached storage. But it doesn't work even if I use C:/.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. Security restrictions in modern web browsers prohibit web sites from loading resources from the local filesystem (*e.g,* `file://`).

Comment: really? if I copy and then paste into the URL box "file:///Z:/Koala" the image opens up just fine in Chrome

Comment: Right, but that only works when you explicitly navigate to a local file (using the URL bar). You can't load, or even link to, local files from online (*e.g,* `http://` or `https://`) sources.